# Getting exception in browser with elgg on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-7, elgg

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.0 with webserver located at `/home/me/Sites`.

Got the message:

### exception:title
An unrecoverable error has occurred and has been logged...

Apache, PHP, and MySQL all work, based on another web installation. Tried installing by downloading elgg files to my webserver's root. Didn't work. Deleted all elgg files and then tried using `composer` to install.

No error messages appear in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` when trying to load the site.

While using `composer create-project elgg/starter-project:dev-master`, found that php-gd, php-xml, and jquery-imgareaselect were missing. After installing these plug-ins/modules installation appeared successful on Terminal. But still got this exception on the browser.

Changed the `.htaccess` file so that Apache would direct to the sub-directory of my localhost. Still not working. There is no settings.php file, nor a settings.example.php file. Tried `composer install` again, which showed no errors. Also no errors show in `error.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Found `php7.0-fpm` (FastCGI Process Manager) has no default `error_log` setting in `php.ini`.

Line 568 in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` has this:

```
;error_log = php_errors.log
```

Uncomment the error_log line. I added a path (made mine `/var/log/apache2/`) and restarted Apache. Elgg is now working.